# "My Day went busy" vs "My day was busy"

Tags: grammar

When starting a sentance telling about how did your day go, do we say my day went busy? Usually went normal looks fine, but went busy doesnt sound that right.

Also If someone asks "how did your day go" instead of "how was ur day" which one's correct/more correct? Lol

Comment: If you [look up *busy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busy), (which you should do, and show that you've done, and show why it isn't clear to you) you'll find that it's an adjective, and modifies nouns, not verbs.

Comment: @Davo That doesn't seem adequate as an answer, because there's nothing wrong with "he went crazy" or "the experiment went wrong."  In fact, saying "he went crazily" or "the experiment went wrongly" seems like a mistake.

Comment: @Casey In *He went crazy,* you are describing **where** he went: crazy as a state of mind. In *He went crazily,* you are describing **how** he went: in a crazy manner. Likewise with *wrong* as the **result** of the experiment, rather than **the manner** in which the experiment went. If one were to mean that the day got very busy toward the end, one could say *My day went busy,* implying busy as the end result - but that would not be idiomatic.

Comment: @Davo Sure, I agree with that. But I think someone asking this question can't necessarily infer all that.

Comment: @Casey - Which is why I posted a *Comment*, to help the OP to find the answer, rather than a fully developed *Answer* to a question which shows no evidence of effort to do research before asking.

Answer (score 2):

"Busy" is an adjective, so it can only describe a noun, not a verb.  Since "day" is a noun, "My day was busy" is correct.  "My day went busy" is incorrect because busy would be describing how the day *went*, not how the day itself was.  Busy cannot describe the verb "went" because it's an adjective.  But you could use the *adverb* "busily" instead.  An adverb describes a verb, so you could technically say "my day went busily." But this would be a strange usage, so just stick with "my day was busy".

Both "how did your day go" and "how was your day" are correct.

Comment: It's unusual but I think you could use "went" to mean "became", so "My day went busy" would mean "My day became busy".  I know this isn't what the OP asked about.

Comment: This might be the right answer, but the logic used to arrive at it doesn't work.  "The experiment went wrongly and the patient went crazily" is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Casey In your examples, "wrongly" and "crazily" are describing the nouns "experiment" and "patient," respectively, NOT the adjective "went."

Comment: Davo's comment explains this much better than I can :)